# Remover array de um array de array

Tags: javascript, array, angularjs

Tenho o seguintes dados em um array

```
var array = [
             ["755", "20", "E", "274", $$hashKey: "0AK"],
             ["756", "20", "E", "274", $$hashKey: "0B7"],
             ["455", "30", "E", "159", $$hashKey: "0BQ"],
             ["757", "20", "E", "274", $$hashKey: "09X"],
             ["456", "30", "E", "159", $$hashKey: "0CB"],
             ["269", "20", "E", "160", $$hashKey: "0CM"],
            ];
```

Desejo remover desse array somente o array que for igual a:

```
var = item = ["757", "20", "E", "274"]
```

Como faço para remover apenas este array?

Comment: Esse array não é um objeto válido em JS. O `$$hashKey: "xxx"` é um objeto?

Comment: Esse $$hashKey é o returno do angularJs usado no ng-repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `filter(fc)`, cujo parâmetro `fc` deve ser uma função que toma como argumento cada elemento do array (em outras palavras, uma função `fc(el)`); no seu caso, cada elemento do array original é **outro** array.

A função `fc(el)` possui a finalidade de dizer se o elemento deve ser mantido (valor de retorno equivalente a `true`), ou então excluído do array resultante da função `filter` (valor resultante `false`).

Ainda, a função `fc(el)` pode ser anônima, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
var array = [
    ["755", "20", "E", "274"],
    ["756", "20", "E", "274"],
    ["455", "30", "E", "159"],
    ["757", "20", "E", "274"],
    ["456", "30", "E", "159"],
    ["269", "20", "E", "160"]
];

// Atenção à função "filter(fc)", cuja função-parâmetro "fc", nesse caso, é anônima:
var array_filtrado = array.filter(function(arr){

    // Para cada array filho ("arr"), verifica se ele é igual a ["757", "20", "E", "274"]:
    var igual = (arr[0] == "757") &&
                (arr[1] == "20" ) &&
                (arr[2] == "E"  ) &&
                (arr[3] == "274") ;

    // Se for igual, exclui do resultado (return false):
    return !igual;
});

console.log(array_filtrado); // Mostra o resultado no console do browser.
```

Obviamente, sempre é possível melhorarmos um código-fonte, especialmente se algum tipo de simplificação puder ser utilizada. Portanto, se assumirmos que os elementos do array são sempre *strings* (por exemplo), é seguro reduzirmos a condição de igualdade de arrays para um simples `a.toString() == b.toString()`:

```js
var array = [
    ["755", "20", "E", "274"],
    ["756", "20", "E", "274"],
    ["455", "30", "E", "159"],
    ["757", "20", "E", "274"],
    ["456", "30", "E", "159"],
    ["269", "20", "E", "160"]
];
var array_filtrado = array.filter(function(arr){
    var igual = arr.toString() == ["757","20","E","274"].toString();
    return !igual;
});
console.log(array_filtrado);
```

O que pode ser compactado ainda mais (coisa que não fiz, para fins didáticos).

Para finalizar, encadear filtros é simples (basta aplicar um novo `filter()` sobre o resultado do `filter()` anterior), e pode ser feito através de duas sintaxes:

```
// Sintaxe 01:
var array_filtrado = array.filter(...);
array_filtrado = array_filtrado.filter(...);
array_filtrado = array_filtrado.filter(...);

// Pode ser reduzido para: (Sintaxe 02)
var array_filtrado = array.filter(...).filter(...).filter(...) ///...
```

Isto, porém, é custoso demais para o teu caso particular, no qual queremos aplicar sempre o mesmo critério de filtragem: excluir os elementos que forem coincidentes com outros determinados elementos. Portanto, sugiro que você crie um array de elementos a serem excluídos:

```js
var array = [
    ["755", "20", "E", "274"],
    ["756", "20", "E", "274"],
    ["455", "30", "E", "159"],
    ["757", "20", "E", "274"],
    ["456", "30", "E", "159"],
    ["269", "20", "E", "160"]
];
var excluir = [
    ["757", "20", "E", "274"],
    ["269", "20", "E", "160"]
];
var array_filtrado = array.filter(function(arr){
    var igual = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < excluir.length; i++){
        if(arr.toString() == excluir[i].toString()) igual = true;
    }
    return !igual;
});
console.log(array_filtrado);
```

Comment: Funcionaria em partes, problema que se eu remover este array ["757","20","E","274"] e for remover outro array, o primeiro volta a aparecer

Comment: Os exemplos mostram como se usa a função `filter()`, e dão uma manha para uma condição de igualdade mais simples; você pode incrementá-los, por exemplo: encadeando exclusões, como você quer. Basta aplicar o segundo filter sobre o *resultado* do primeiro, ou seja, sobre o `array_filtrado` :D

Comment: De qualquer forma, incrementei a resposta com mais um exemplo, que resolverá seu problema sem precisar encadear filtros (o que, diga-se de passagem, tornaria a manutenção do código um ***pesadelo***!).

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o `delete (array[valor do indice do array que quer apagar]);`